# Maintain collapse state on postback ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4, webforms

I have two different forms that collapse and show either one or the other and there's a button to control them.

```
<div>
    <button type="button" 
            data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target=".multi-collapse" 
            aria-expanded="false" 
            aria-controls="form1 form2"> Change Form
    </button>

    <div class="collapse multi-collapse show" id="form1">
        <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" 
                          OnSelectedIndexChanged="SetDdl2ValuesBasedOnWhatIsSelectedOnDdl1" 
                          ID="Ddl1" 
                          runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl2" 
                          runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="SubmitBtn"
    <\div>

    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="form2">
        <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" 
                          OnSelectedIndexChanged="SetDdl2ValuesBasedOnWhatIsSelectedOnDdl1" 
                          ID="Ddl1" 
                          runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl2" 
                          runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="SubmitBtn"
    <\div>
</div>
```

My problem is that whenever theres a post back I lose the collapse state of the forms and it goes back to  the form1 showing and form2 hiding.

I want to save the state of the collapsables so they stay the same after a postback and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Use cookies or store the state in a HiddenField and apply after PostBack.

Comment: Or store the state in URL as query parameter. Here is a list from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

I have done this through **PageRequestManager**, of course preserving the state of one or two divs, in your case there are two but if there are more, the solution I give is quite difficult but functional:

**ASPX Code:**

Add your controls in *UpdatePanel*

```
<div>
    <button type="button" 
            data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target=".multi-collapse" 
            aria-expanded="false" 
            aria-controls="form1 form2"> Change Form
    </button>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        
            <div class="collapse multi-collapse show" id="form1">
                <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" 
                                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="Ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                  ID="Ddl1" 
                                  runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl2" 
                                  runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="btn1" />
            </div>

            <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="form2">
                <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" 
                                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                  ID="DropDownList1" 
                                  runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" 
                                  runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2" OnClick="Button1_Click1" Text="btn2" />
            </div>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

The event *add_beginRequest* is an event that is fired when a Postback starts and it is possible to save the DOM state, while *add_endRequest* is the event that is fired when the panel is updated and the Postback ends, this is where the controls are arranged according to the conditions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var statusForm1 = false,
        statusForm2 = false;

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {

        if (statusForm1) {
            $('#form1').collapse('show');
        }
        if (statusForm2) {
            $('#form2').collapse('show');
        }

    }

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {

        statusForm1 = $('#form1').is(":visible");
        statusForm2 = $('#form2').is(":visible");

    }

    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Very nice explanation and easy to read code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple and straight forward way of doing this which is, adding the class `show` to the `div` that you want to actually show. So, in order to do it, you must set both the `div`s to run at server. Here is my proposed idea for this problem:

```
<div class="collapse multi-collapse show" id="myform1" runat="server"> 
    <!-- because in aspx, there is already a form1 form which is parent of all elements that runs at server -->
    <!-- Other elements go here -->
</div>

<div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="myform2" runat="server">
    <!-- Other elements go here -->
</div>
```

And on server events, you need to hide and show the respective `divs` by adding the classes to them.

```
protected void SubmitBtn1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // DoStuff(); 
    ShowMyForm1();

}
protected void SubmitBtn2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // DoStuff(); 
    ShowMyForm2();

}

protected void SetDdl2ValuesBasedOnWhatIsSelectedOnDdl1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // DoStuff();
    // I assume this dropdown is in second form div.
    ShowMyForm2();

}
private void ShowMyForm1()
{
    myform1.Attributes["class"] = "collapse multi-collapse show"; // this will show the div
    myform2.Attributes["class"] = "collapse multi-collapse"; // this will hide the div.
}
private void ShowMyForm2()
{
    myform1.Attributes["class"] = "collapse multi-collapse"; // this will hide the div
    myform2.Attributes["class"] = "collapse multi-collapse show"; // this will show the div
}
```

Notice, I have given two events for your submit button because it was appearing on both the forms and it had the same `ID` for it, which is not allowed for server controls. An `ID` must be unique. And your `form2` has all the elements duplicated in it from the `form1`

So, to differentiate between those elements, You will have to give them different `ID`s.